# Python can't find BBIO.GPIO library on Beaglebone

Tags: python, beagleboard, gpio, angstrom-linux

I'm using the Beaglebone and I had installed this software:
 http://learn.adafruit.com/setting-up-io-python-library-on-beaglebone-black/installation
the test works fine (webpage test) but when I'm trying to run my first program it doesn't recognize the library the mistake is:

```
import BBIO.GPIO as GPIO
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named BBIO.GPIO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered what might be a similar problem around the same time as you.

The Adafruit library has changed, and the instructions have been updated. It might be worth heading over to http://learn.adafruit.com/setting-up-io-python-library-on-beaglebone-black and starting again.

The library's name has been changed as well, so you won't have any collision errors.

Good luck!